# Accessing localhost through a proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, localhost

A quick background of my situation:
I'm a web developer that frequently uses IIS Express to debug web applications via `localhost`. I've recently purchased a proxy because I'm about to travel abroad and want to keep a static IP in the process.

**My problem:**
Each time I try to debug a web app (`localhost:port`) or go to `127.0.0.1` in my browser I get the following
[image]

I've setup my proxy settings as such:
[image]
I don't want to bypass for local requests because then it defeats the purpose of my goal as my IP will always change depending where I'm connecting from.

My understanding is that my request is going out to my proxy and then trying to ping 127.0.0.1 (my pc) which seems impossible... I'm not sure, I'm not a networking guy. If it helps, here's my hosts file located in the drivers/etc folder

[image]

**Is it possible to access my local host via my proxy?**

Comment: absolutely impossible. the only way that will work is if you give up using localhost, and use the external IP address of the machine (and it must be an IP that is visible to the proxy, so if the proxy is on the internet, you will have to port forward to let the traffic back in). Much better to use a proxy switch addon for your browser so you can enable/disable proxying at will. 127.0.0.1 isn't just your loopback address, it is also the proxies, so anything you send to the proxy with 127.0.0.1 as destination will be delivered to the proxy server itself.

Comment: Local requests are actually fine. What I really need is our remote services (such as databases, search indexes etc) always see a static IP. So when I launch these web apps they should be accessing our remote SQL server etc through the proxy.

Comment: it will work if you use any other IP or DNS name if (and only if) the IP and a DNS server hosting the name are accessible to it. the problem you are having is specific to loopback addresses like those in the 127.X.Y.Z range. Any other address will proxy fine as long as the name can be looked up and/or the ip is reachable. are the proxy, DB and web services on the LAN?

Comment: Nope, they are completely remote. The proxy is from http://blazingseollc.com/proxy/ while our databases etc are all hosted on AWS. I'm thinking I may have to purchase a cheap machine to run linux and my own proxy from my home. I'm just not 100% confident that would be stable enough if I am moving from country to country.

Comment: in that case am I missing the place where you configure the remote IP of the remote services? as long as you point to the remote servers instead of localhost, and they don't initiate connections to your application, everything should work fine. I'm not understanding why you have configured your host-file in that manner or why you are trying to access remote addresses via your localhost/loopback address.

Answer (score -1):

"Bypass proxy for local addresses" should work just fine. After all, it only takes effect when connecting *to* local addresses – ones that the proxy couldn't possibly reach *anyway*.

Also look under the "Advanced" tab for an exclusion list. You could list all your custom `whatever.localhost` domains in there.